# How install uuid in centos5.8

Tags: centos, uuid

I have tried some tutorials from internet, like `yum install libuuid-devel`, but not works.

```bash
sh-3.2# yum install libuuid-devel
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
C5.8-base                                                                                                | 1.1 kB     00:00     
C5.8-centosplus                                                                                          | 1.9 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
No package libuuid-devel available.
Nothing to do
```

Then i want to compile uuid from source code, but not found uuid source code location.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo yum install uuid-devel
```